# Azure REST API - Get total no. policies given Policy Assignment ID

Tags: azure, azure-rest-api

Is there anyone who knows how I can get the total number of policies for a given Policy Assignment ID using Azure's REST API?

I've tried various endpoints but have not been able to get the total count. On the portal you can see the total number of policies on the **Policy | Compliance** page.

I hope someone can help me figure this out.

Comment: Do you mean Policy Assignment ID or Policy Definition ID?

Comment: @GauravMantri The **Policy Assignment ID**. If you have the Azure portal open,  you can try to go to "Policy -> Compliance -> Pick an Assignment from the list" Now on this page you can see a list of policies for that assignment. I want to retrieve the number of policies presented on this list.

Comment: @Sridevi That is the number of non-compliant resources. Your page looks different to mine, on the right side of that statistic, I have a "Non-compliant policies" number. I was able to find an endpoint that solved my issue. Please see answer if interested.

Comment: @GauravMantri I was incorrect. It was indeed on the Policy Definition ID as you had mentioned, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an endpoint that retrieves all policy definitions based on a policy definition ID. By having this, I was able to do a `.Count` operation to get the total number of policies.

The endpoint used was:

```
https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions/{policyDefinitionId}?api-version=2021-06-01
```

By doing a `.count` on `{JSON_RESULT}.properties.policyDefinitions` I was able to get the total number of policies for that policy definition id.